# Is there a way to rename the text/label for a view i.e. change the word in the header 'Agenda' to 'My Text'?

Tags: fullcalendar

in FullCalendar - I'm trying to change the label/text for the word 'Agenda' in the header, to a custom name - Does anyone know if there is a way to do this please?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the word "Agenda" in your calendar? It's not there by default - see https://fullcalendar.io/#demos . If you have a specific issue, please show your code. If you've written some code which adds that word, then presumably you could remove that code again. In general, control of what appears in the header area above the calendar is listed in the docs under this section: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/toolbar . What have you researched? What have you tried?

Comment: "Agenda" is simply a view - not on the default calendar, but a standard view nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, I know. But that word does not appear on the calendar unless you specifically code it to do so (maybe you added a button for an "agenda" view with a custom duration, perhaps? So if you added it, you can remove it or replace it - custom views can be given a different name in their settings. That was my point.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else that would like to rename the default label/text that appears in the header (and footer) it seems that it can be done by using the following code when defining the calendar object.
see: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/buttonText

Text that will be displayed on buttons of the header/footer.

Object, default:

```
{
  today:    'today',
  month:    'month',
  week:     'week',
  day:      'day',
  list:     'list'
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: none of those settings would affect the word "agenda" so far as I can see? What change did you make, compared to the default settings, to actually affect your specific scenario? It's unclear from this answer.